# Q_PROPERTY: MEMBER vs READ/WRITE

Tags: c++, qt, properties, macros, member

I was reading the documentation of Qt 5.5 about Q_PROPERTY macro, but I can't understand it well enought.

I understand that you can use in this macro with the keyword MEMBER or the accessors READ/WRITE instead. If you use keyword MEMBER you don't have to write the accessors, because you can access to your private data member (the property) with the use of setProperty() and Property(), like a set and get.

The point is: is there any difference between using MEMBER and using READ/WRITE? 
when should you use one and when the other way?

For if necessary:

Example of using MEMBER:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString text MEMBER m_text NOTIFY textChanged)
```

Example of using READ/WRITE:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int propX READ getX WRITE setX)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By reading carefully the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html), it seems to me that there are slightly, important differences.

First of all:

> A MEMBER variable association is required if no READ accessor function is specified. This makes the given member variable readable and writable without the need of creating READ and WRITE accessor functions.

That means that you can either use `MEMBER` and rely on auto generated, trivial accessor functions or define for yourself those functions if they happen to be more complex than a defaulted one.

In other terms, if your accessor functions are all the way the same, as an example:

```
int propName() const { return prop; }
```

Thus, `MEMBER` is fine. It does not if you have something like:

```
int propName() const { return superComplexMathUsedToComputeProp(); }
```

Also, note that:

> The READ, WRITE, and RESET functions can be inherited. They can also be virtual.

If you are dealing with a hierarchy, maybe you want them to be inherited, so maybe to go with `READ` and `WRITE` would be better.

Which is the best and what to use depends on the specific problem.

Comment: thanks a lot. Finally it's like I thought, but it's better to clear it up :)

Comment: @Pablo You are welcome, I admit that sometimes the documentation must be read twice to fully understand what's the purpose behind a choice and how it will affect our codebase. Personally, I prefer to use the `READ`/`WRITE` accessor functions because, at least to me, it's easier to understand what's happening in the code by simply looking at it.

Comment: @skpjack my problem is that sometimes when I read the documentation I feel lost. It give for granted that you know and understand 'underlying things' . The documentation is very efficient to someone who has wide experience, but someone who is starting with the framework may feel lost.

Comment: This answer is wrong : MEMBER does not general trivial getters and setters at all.

Answer (score 7):

The MEMBER creates just ReadProperty and WriteProperty features in qt meta object system(see the generated moc file). This is useful for interfacing with QMLs. In order to use property in c++, the getters and setters has to be implemented as well.

So:

- MEMBER -> just for QMLs
- READ, WRITE, NOTIFY -> C++ and QML

If you would like to avoid programming trivial getters and setters, define your own makro wrapping Q_PROPERTY.

Comment: It seems you're still able to access the `MEMBER` property from C++ by using the `QObject::setProperty( name, value ), QObject::property( name )` member functions. But I think it's better to have the `READ/WRITE` instead for this purpose.