# How to use a Enum as QProperty and update it using a stylesheet?

Tags: c++, qt

How to use an Enum as QProperty and update its value using a stylesheet?

```
class Gallery : public QScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int horizontalSpacing MEMBER horizontalSpacing) 
    Q_PROPERTY(Orientation orientation MEMBER orientation WRITE setOrientation)

public:
    int horizontalSpacing;

    enum Orientation { TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT };
    Orientation orientation;
    void setOrientation(Orientation orientation);
};
```

Using:

```
Gallery
{
    qproperty-horizontalSpacing: 30;
    qproperty-orientation: "left";
}
```

the `setOrientation` function is not called.
Using:

```
Gallery
{
    qproperty-horizontalSpacing: 30;
    qproperty-orientation: left;
}
```

The function is called but, the value of `orientation` is `19`, what does this mean?

```
void Gallery::setOrientation(Orientation orientation)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems using `MEMBER` with one accessor (`WRITE` in this case) to handle a custom property, causes undefined behavior that is noticed when fetching the `int` value of `Orientation` enum.

To work around that, here are 2 solutions, and both require adding `Q_ENUM(someEnum)`:

---

### Solution 1:

Use only `READ` and `WRITE` to set `orientation`:

```
class Gallery : public QScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Orientation orientation READ getOrientation WRITE setOrientation)

public:
    enum Orientation { TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT };
    Orientation orientation;
    Q_ENUM(Orientation)

    void setOrientation(Orientation orient)
    {
        orientation = orient;
    }
    Orientation getOrientation()
    {
        return orientation;
    }
};
```

When setting stylesheet, quotes are mandatory, as well as matching the casing, which is all uppercase in this case:

```
Gallery
{
    qproperty-orientation: "LEFT";
}
```

---

### Solution 2:

Use `MEMBER` on its own:

```
class Gallery : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Orientation orientation MEMBER orientation)

public:
    enum Orientation { TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT };
    Orientation orientation;
    Q_ENUM(Orientation)
};
```

Same rules for the stylesheet.

---

I'll include this explanation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34350099/17726418) on [Q_PROPERTY: MEMBER vs READ/WRITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349814/q-property-member-vs-read-write):

> ...you can either use `MEMBER` and rely on auto generated, trivial accessor functions or define for yourself those functions if they happen to be more complex than a defaulted one.

---

For more:

- [Qt Documentation: The Property System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)